# ApplicationPidFileWriter doesn't produce .pid file on Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot

The following setup doesn't seem to generate .pid file (as described here - http://www.kubrynski.com/2014/05/managing-spring-boot-application.html:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication app = new SpringApplication(BrokerFeedApplication.class);
        app.addListeners(new ApplicationPidFileWriter());
        app.run(BrokerFeedApplication.class, args);
    }
```

```xml
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By using the [`static run(Object source, String... args)`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/SpringApplication.html#run-java.lang.Object-java.lang.String...-) method in the last line you're disregarding the `app` configuration you did in the first two lines. See [Javadoc](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/SpringApplication.html#run-java.lang.Object-java.lang.String...-) (emphasis mine):

> Static **helper** that can be used to run a SpringApplication from the specified source using default settings.

Change the last line to use the [`run(java.lang.String...)`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/SpringApplication.html#run-java.lang.String...-) instance method to make use the previously registered listener, i.e. change:

```java
app.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
```

to

```
app.run(args);
```